# Limits (discontinuity)

Tags: limits, continuity

Determine the points where the function with domain R is not continuous. Identify as removable or an essential discontinuity.

$$
f(x)=  
\begin{cases}
 &\frac{x^2-1}{x-1} \text{ if } x\neq 1 \\ 
 & \;\; \\
 & 1 \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; \text{ if } x= 1 
\end{cases} 
$$

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: I got the limit as x approaches 1 from the negative direction on the first function and i got x+1 and i got the limit as x approaches 1 from the positive direction on the second function which results in 1. so i think its not continuos at 1 ? but i don't if its removable or essential discontinuity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that 
$$\frac{x^2-1}{x-1}=\frac{(x-1)(x+1)}{x-1}=(x+1),\ \forall\ x\ne 1$$
so we have
$$\lim_{x\to1}f(x)=\lim_{x\to1}\frac{x^2-1}{x-1}=\lim_{x\to1}x+1=2\neq f(1)=1$$
so your function isn't continuous at $1$ but since it has a **finite limit** at this point then this discontinuity is **removable**.